# Android room data relations

Tags: gson, android-room

I have multiple object tyes inside a parent class.Say I have a College class as below

```
data class College(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id:String,
    val name: String? = null,
    val description: String? = null,
    val groups: List<Group>? = null,
    val status: String? = null,
)

data class Group(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id:String,
    val name: String? = null,
    val description: String? = null,
    val students: List<Students>? = null,
)
```

The problem here is there is not relational id in child tables.I mean JSON received don't give relation of groups inside college with collegeId in Groups table or relation of students in group table.

The JSON received is as below

```
"college": [
{
  "id": "collegeid",
  "groups": [
    "id": "groupid"
    "name": "BCOM" // Here no collegeId  is mentioned inside it
  ]
}
```

If is use @Embedded keyword it is throwing "Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor".

Is there anyway with above JSON I can set the id of college inside group and use it as foreign key for relations.

I have used Typeconverters and is working fine but now I need to create relations between these tables with above type of JSON.

I use Gson parsing

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you may be getting mixed up with how to utilise relationships/tables.

**IF** you have

```
@Entity
data class College(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id:String,
    val name: String? = null,
    val description: String? = null,
    val groups: List<Group>? = null,
    val status: String? = null,
)
```

this will be a table where the groups column will (in theory) contain a List of Groups, there is no relationship as there is just a column with a single stream of data (probably as JSON string).

However, if you wanted to have a table with the Colleges, a table with the Groups and a table with the Students then you wouldn't embed the Groups within the College and subsequently the Students within the Groups.

Rather, if you want to approach this from a db relationship aspect. Assuming that a Group MUST belong to one and only one College and that a Student MUST only belong to a single Group then you would have something along the lines of:-

```
@Entity
data class College(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id:String,
    val name: String? = null,
    val description: String? = null,
    //val groups: List<Group>? = null, //<<<<< NO NEED (see Group)
    val status: String? = null,
)

@Entity
data class Group(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id:String,
    val name: String? = null,
    val description: String? = null,
    //val students: List<Students>? = null, //<<<<< NO NEED (similar to Group)
    val collegeId: String //<<<<< ADDED for relationships to parent College
)
```

- similar with Students
- the crucial factor here is the new column/field/variable collegeId, which should contain the id of the parent college.

To get the College(s) with the related groups then you can have a class that has @Embedded annotation for the parent (the College) and @Relation annotation for the children (Groups). e.g.

```
data class CollegeWithRelatedGroups(
    @Embedded
    val college: College,
    @Relation(
        entity = Group::class,
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "collegeId"
    )
    val groups: List<Group>
)
```

**Working Example**

Here's a working example that uses the above and adds (inserts) 3 Colleges, and then 6 Groups. The first College has 3 related Groups, the second 2 and the third 1.

The example then extracts the Colleges with the related Groups outputting the result to the log.

**College** and also **CollegeWithRelatedGroups**

```
@Entity
data class College(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id:String,
    val name: String? = null,
    val description: String? = null,
    //val groups: List<Group>? = null,
    val status: String? = null
)

data class CollegeWithRelatedGroups(
    @Embedded
    val college: College,
    @Relation(
        entity = Group::class,
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "collegeId"
    )
    val groups: List<Group>
)
```

**Group** (with Foreign Key constraint)

```
@Entity(
    /* Optional but suggested Foreign Key to enforce referential integrity
     */
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = College::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["collegeId"],
            /* Optional within Foreign Key - helps maintain referential integrity (if CASCADE)

                ON DELETE will delete the Groups that are related to a College if the College is deleted
                ON UPDATE will change the collegeId of Groups that are related to a College if the id of the College is changed
             */
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class Group(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id:String,
    val name: String? = null,
    val description: String? = null,
    //val students: List<Student>? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true) /* faster to access via relationship if indexed */
    val collegeId: String
)
```

**AllDao**

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(college: College): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(group: Group): Long
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM college")
    fun getCollegesWithRelatedGroups(): List<CollegeWithRelatedGroups>

}
```

**TheDatabase** (note for brevity and convenience allows main thread processing)

```
@Database(entities = [College::class, Group::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao
    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, TheDatabase::class.java, "the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- Note there is no need for TypeConverters as objects are not being stored (aka simple types are stored)

**Activity Code** (MainActivity in this case)

```
const val TAG = "DBINFO"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()

        dao.insert(College("College1","The first College","Opened"))
        dao.insert(College("College2","The second College","Opened"))
        dao.insert(College("New College","A new College","Being built"))

        dao.insert(Group("GroupA","Group A or something","The first Group - hence A","College1",))
        dao.insert(Group("GroupB","Group B or whatever"," The second Group ...", "College2"))
        dao.insert(Group("GroupC","Group C on so on","The third Group ...","New College"))
        dao.insert(Group("GroupX","Group X ...","The Xth group","College1"))
        dao.insert(Group("GroupY","...","...","College1"))
        dao.insert(Group("GroupZ","...","...","College2"))

        for (cwrg in dao.getCollegesWithRelatedGroups()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"College is ID=${cwrg.college.id} Desc=${cwrg.college.description} Name=${cwrg.college.name} Status=${cwrg.college.name}\nIt has ${cwrg.groups.size} Groups. They are:-")
            for (g in cwrg.groups) {
                Log.d(TAG,"\n\t\tGroup is ID=${g.id} Name=${g.name} Desc=${g.description} it reference CollegeID=${g.collegeId}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- **Note** The status has not been supplied for the Colleges. so they will be null.

**RESULT** the log includes :-

```
D/DBINFO: College is ID=College1 Desc=Opened Name=The first College Status=The first College
    It has 3 Groups. They are:-
D/DBINFO:       Group is ID=GroupA Name=Group A or something Desc=The first Group - hence A it reference CollegeID=College1
D/DBINFO:       Group is ID=GroupX Name=Group X ... Desc=The Xth group it reference CollegeID=College1
D/DBINFO:       Group is ID=GroupY Name=... Desc=... it reference CollegeID=College1


D/DBINFO: College is ID=College2 Desc=Opened Name=The second College Status=The second College
    It has 2 Groups. They are:-
D/DBINFO:       Group is ID=GroupB Name=Group B or whatever Desc= The second Group ... it reference CollegeID=College2
D/DBINFO:       Group is ID=GroupZ Name=... Desc=... it reference CollegeID=College2


D/DBINFO: College is ID=New College Desc=Being built Name=A new College Status=A new College
    It has 1 Groups. They are:-
D/DBINFO:       Group is ID=GroupC Name=Group C on so on Desc=The third Group ... it reference CollegeID=New College
```

The Database via App Inspection :-

[image]

and

[image]